# IHTMLDocument2::get_body fails in CHtmlView for IE 11

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, com

We've hit a simple, but critical, problem: IHTMLDocument2::get_body works in our embedded browser (CHtmlView) for IE7, but not IE11.  We really want to start using the newer version, but this is a killer right now.

We use Visual Studio 2010.  Native (unmanaged) C++.  Problem occurs in both 32 and 64 bit builds.  I don't know where this started failing (IE8?  IE9?  IE10?).   OnNavigateComplete2 has fired before we try to call this function.

Here's our code, which has worked for us for a long time:

```
ComPtr<IHTMLTxtRange> CHighlightHTML::GetRange(ComPtr<IHTMLDocument2> document)
{
    ComPtr<IHTMLElement> elt;
    ComPtr<IHTMLBodyElement> body;

    if( SUCCEEDED(document->get_body(&elt.ReleaseGetValue())) )
        body = elt;

    if( body.IsValid() )
    {
        // Create a range from the entire body element.
        ComPtr<IHTMLTxtRange> range;
        CHECK_COM(body, createTextRange(&range.ReleaseGetValue()));
        return range;               
    }
}
```

But when we set the registry key:
HKCU/Software/Microsoft/Internet Explorer/Main/FeatureControl/FEATURE_BROWSER_EMULATION

to 11000 for our .exe, then elt == NULL (so fails the body.IsValid() test)

If we have not set the registry key, or set the key to 7000 (so browser control is IE7), then it works again.

Help!

Answer (score 1):

Robert Aldwinckle gave me the answer on the msdn forum.  I needed to set the registry value to 11001 instead of 11000:

```
11001 (0x2AF9   Internet Explorer 11. Webpages are displayed in IE11 edge mode, regardless of the !DOCTYPE directive.
11000 (0x2AF8)  IE11. Webpages containing standards-based !DOCTYPE directives are displayed in IE11 edge mode. Default value for IE11.
```

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsazure/en-US/0e1e52da-e462-42fd-bc46-567d08225d79/ihtmldocument2getbody-fails-in-chtmlview-for-ie-11?forum=iewebdevelopment

Comment: Thank you.  Still, it doesn't explain why `get_body()` returns `NULL` otherwise.  I think you need to wait for the [`DocumentComplete` event](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768329.aspx) or the [`READYSTATE_COMPLETE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb268229.aspx) value in the [`ReadyState`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752066.aspx) property.  The document might still be downloading when [`NavigateComplete2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa768334.aspx) is fired.

Comment: In our case, DocumentComplete has already fired as well (the page is simple, all from the local machine, and the failing function runs in response to UI action).  You're right that I should've mentioned that rather than NavigationComplete in my question.  You're also right that I still don't know why get_body returns NULL and, while I'd like to really understand this, at least this lets me get things moving again.